# Custom URL Rewriting in Classic ASP

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have been trying to rewrite the URL in classic ASP. I am currently using IIS 7.5. I tried to use the URL Rewrite plugin which converts the following link:

http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?id=19

into something like this:

blog.johnavis.com/19/

blog.johnavis.com/id/19/

blog.johnavis.com/blog/default/19

blog.johnavis.com/blog/default/id/19

I want to convert into something like this:
http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/myblog/

Can that be achieved? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, that's my blog you used as an example! Have been meaning to add URL rewriting to it for ages.

Comment: At least you prompted me into action. I added URL rewriting to my blog at last. I used the custom 404 error method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all the rewrite module does is to edit your web.config file.  You're probably better off editing the file yourself.  You'll find that it has created a section called rewrite, add the following rule

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="My Blog">
                    <match url="blog/myblog/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="blog/default.asp?id=19" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: I did see that change in my web.config file. That raises my other question. What if I want to get a value dynamically from the page to rewrite in URL. For Example, the same URL in my question has a text 'Alienware' in a label. Can I get the URL to be displayed like this:  http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/alienware

Comment: If you're looking for a regex solution then you would need to use the name of the blog in your querystring - ie `blog.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?name=alienware`.  Otherwise you would probably need a separate rule for each blog

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating URL rewrite rule in IIS Manager by defining a pattern. Use the following links to learn about that.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-video-walkthrough

Hope this helps...